# Extending smooth function on subset to manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

I want to prove this proposition:

> **Proposition:** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold that is Hausdorff and $2^{nd}$ countable. Let $U \subseteq M$ be open and let $p \in U$ be some point. If $f : U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function, then there exists another smooth function $\widetilde{f} : M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ and $\widetilde{f}$ coincide in a neighbourhood of $p$.

Now my (attempt at a) proof is as follows:

**1.)**  $\enspace$ Let $(\varphi, V)$ be a chart around $p$. Then $(\varphi, U \cap V)$ is also a chart around $p$ and w.l.o.g. let $\varphi(p) = 0$.

**2.)**  $\enspace$ Choose an open ball $B_r(0)$ around $\varphi(p) = 0$ in the coordinate space such that $\overline{B_r(0)} \subseteq \varphi(U \cap V)$.

**3.)**  $\enspace$ Then the preimage $\varphi^{-1} \Big( \overline{B_r(0)} \Big) = : W$ is closed in $M$.

Here I make use of a lemma stating the following:

> **Lemma:** If $\mathcal{O}$ is an open subset of $M$ and $W \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ is closed, then there exists a smooth function $g : M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $g \, |_{W} = 1$ and $g \, |_{M \backslash \mathcal{O}} = 0$.

**4.)**  $\enspace$ Identifying $\mathcal{O} = U \cap V$, I now set the function $\widetilde{f}$ to be

$$ \widetilde{f}(p) \enspace = \enspace \begin{cases} g(p) \cdot f(p) \enspace , & \quad p \in U \cap V \\
{} & \\
0 \enspace , & \quad p \in (U \cap V)^c \end{cases} $$

**5.)**  $\enspace$ By what has been said so far, one knows that:

$$ \widetilde{f} \, |_W \enspace = \enspace \underbrace{g \, |_W}_{= \, 1} \cdot f \, |_W \enspace = \enspace f \, |_W \quad , \qquad \widetilde{f} \, |_{(U \cap V)^c} \enspace = \enspace g \, |_{(U \cap V)^c} \enspace = \enspace 0$$

The (closed) subset $W$ is the set on which the function $\widetilde{f}$ coincides with $f$ as desired. Products of smooth functions are smooth again and so the first "case" of $\widetilde{f}$ is smooth. Trivially, the second "case" of $\widetilde{f}$ is also smooth.

The question is: **How do I proof smoothness at the boundary of $U \cap V$**, i.e. on the set where these two cases "meet"? To be more specific: $g$ goes to zero when approaching the boundary of $U \cap V$ but $f$ could be diverging there and could consequently cancel the "cutoff" that $g$ provides, right? How can this be prevented?

---

---

**EDIT 1:**

By suggestion of *peek-a-boo* (provided that I did understand his hint correctly), I revise my reasoning as follows:

**1.)**  $\enspace$ see above.

**2.)**  $\enspace$ Choose an open ball $B_r(0) \subseteq \varphi(U \cap V)$ around $\varphi(p) = 0$ such that $B_r(0) \cap \partial \varphi(U \cap V) = \emptyset$ and choose another ball $B_{r/2}(0)$.

**3.)**  $\enspace$ The preimage $\varphi^{-1} \Big( B_r(0) \Big) =: \mathcal{O}$ is open in $M$ and the preimage $\varphi^{-1} \Big( \overline{B_{r/2}(0)} \Big) =: W$ is closed in $M$ with $W \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ and most importantly

$$\mathcal{O} \cap \partial(U \cap V) \enspace = \enspace \emptyset \quad \overset{\mathcal{O} \subseteq U \cap V}{\Longrightarrow} \quad  \mathcal{O} \cap \partial U \enspace = \enspace \emptyset$$

**4.)**  $\enspace$ Now use the lemma, and define

$$ \widetilde{f}(p) \enspace = \enspace \begin{cases} g(p) \cdot f(p) \enspace , & \quad p \in \mathcal{O} \\
{} & \\
0 \enspace , & \quad p \in M \backslash \mathcal{O} \end{cases} $$

**5.)**  $\enspace$ By what has been said so far, one knows that:

$$ \widetilde{f} \, |_W \enspace = \enspace \underbrace{g \, |_W}_{= \, 1} \cdot f \, |_W \enspace = \enspace f \, |_W \quad , \qquad \widetilde{f} \, |_{ M \backslash \mathcal{O}} \enspace = \enspace g \, |_{ M \backslash \mathcal{O}} \enspace = \enspace 0$$

**6.)**  $\enspace$ The function $f$ can only diverge on the boundary of $U$, otherwise there would be points in $U$ at which $f$ is not defined, contradicting the definition of $f$ as a function $f : U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. So $f$ does not diverge on $\mathcal{O} \subseteq U$. Therefore, the product $g \cdot f$ does indeed provide a cutoff at the boundary of $\mathcal{O}$ - and so $\widetilde{f}$ is smooth everywhere.

Comment: Perhaps I'm overlooking something, but your lemma doesn't seem to be strong enough. But a proof of the theorem is still pretty easy. Let $W=\phi^{-1}(\overline{B_{r}(0)})$  and $W'=\phi^{-1}(B_{r/2}(0))$. Then, you can find a smooth function $g:M\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $g|_{W'}=1$ and $g|_{W^c}=0$ (i.e a function which is $1$ on a small open set, zero outside a slightly larger closed set, and this is all contained in your original open set $\mathcal{O}$ of interest). Can you prove this result, and can you see how to use this to prove the theorem?

Comment: Another way of saying this is that for any open $\Omega\subset M$ and any $p\in \Omega$, there is a smooth $g:M\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $g=1$ in some neighborhood of $p$, and $\text{supp}(g):=\overline{\{q\in M\,:\, g(q)\neq 0\}}\subset \Omega$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I updated my question. The revised proof now chooses two open balls $B_r(0)$ and $B_{r/2}(0)$ in the coordinate space which provide both the open set $\mathcal{O}$ and the closed set $W$ within the **Lemma**. The difference now is that the preimage of both balls do not intersect the boundary of $U$ (by construction) and therefore one does not have a problem with $f$ diverging at the boundary. Does this (updated) proof work, and is this what you were hinting at?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. Tu's very readable [book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Manifolds-Second-Universitext/dp/1441973990) includes a section on bump functions, which you might find useful. If you're studying differential geometry, bump functions and partitions of unity are tools you should have in the kit.